# Is it possible for Google Places API to notify users of any quiet locations within close proximity?

Tags: google-places-api

I would like to ask whether Google Places API is able to notify users of any quiet places within their region?

I am creating an application which is targeted towards people with hearing loss and one of the features of the application is to enable users with hearing loss to locate a quiet place in order to rest their ears. For instance, if a user is currently in a club for extended periods of time and requires a quiet place to rest his ears away from the loud music, the app will be able to direct the user to the desired location quickly and efficiently.

Comment: seems a bit overkill to make such app? wouldnt it be enough to step out of the club to the parking lot? how would you keep you quiet places database up to date? google doesnt provide that data thou conceivably you could build such database croudsourcing the app microphone to send noise stats to a server.

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Try using geofencing and notify user if he/she reach near by such loactions

> [Example1](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation) , [Example2](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) , [Example3](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps) [Example4](http://paulusworld.com/technical/android-geofences) ,
>   [Example5](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/implementing-map-and-geofence-features-in-android-business-apps)